# How to create a UIWebView of a feature from another website (Like osx Dashboard)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, screen-scraping

Hi there I am wanting to make a personal rain radar application with information from my local weather service website.
I would like to have only the rain radar display in my application that you are able to see in this link

http://www.metservice.com/national/maps-rain-radar/rain-radar/auckland

I am wondering if it is possible to call the images from and create my own little player. I used googles source viewer and have figured out which parts of the code contain the images but I'm just not sure how I could make use of them.

[image]
[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a fair amount of work ahead of you, but this would be a good learning experience.

First, you'll need to obtain the contents of the web page in HTML form. Apple has a tutorial demonstrating how to use `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` to do so:

[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Once you have obtained the data from that link, you can skip creating an `NSString`, and just jump right into an XML parser. Though, if you do need to create a string for other uses, you can use:

```
NSString *stringWithHTMLData =
            [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webPageData
                              encoding:NSStringUTF8Encoding];
```

Once you have the HTML data, you can use an XML parser to look through the HTML and find the URLs of the images you want to display:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webPageData];
```

The `NSXMLParser` class reference would be of help in determining how to traverse the HTML:

[NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Once you have parsed the URLs and have them, you can actually create the `NSImage` objects with the URLs, and they will lazily load from the web page:

```
NSURL *firstImageURL = ...;
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:firstImageURL];
// Do something with the image, like adding it to a view somewhere
```

Comment: cool I get it. I have abit of experience with NSXMLParser now from doing some Rss comic feed readers etc. I have a little bit of experience with NSURLRequest.. but not much I have been using the ASIHTTPRequest library.. which I think I might use for this also.. Thanks very much for the reply.. I am going to try this out tonight.. But I defiantly get what to do now. Thanks very much :)

Comment: The only thing being is that the image names change.. so not to sure what to do there but I guess I will find out when I give it a try :)

Comment: Its weird, the HTML output dosnt show all the images but I can find them all when I "inspect elements"..

Comment: Yea, they're using jQuery to change the `src` of that image tag when you press the prev/next buttons. I'm not really a JavaScript expert so I'm not entirely sure how they're jumping through those images, but there must be an array or directory somewhere.